# Simple Acts_as_mappable "through" not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geokit

Using the geokit-rails gem, I have:

`Employer.rb` model, with lng & lat attributes:

has_many :jobs, dependent: :destroy
  acts_as_mappable

`Job.rb` model, with no lng or lat

acts_as_mappable :through => :employer

If I try `Job.within(3, origin: [0, 0])` in the console, I get this error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "employers"
LINE 2: ...      (ACOS(least(1,COS(0.0)*COS(0.0)*COS(RADIANS(employers....
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:

```
Job.joins(:employer).within(3, origin: [0, 0])
```

Comment: While this looks like an accurate answer, you should explain why this works properly along with the code.